# The expression "days after.."

Tags: expressions

> Days after the Berlin Wall fell, [something happened].

What does "Days after.." mean? Does it mean "A few days after.."?

Comment: Probably, but more context would be needed to say for sure.

Comment: Days after the Berlin Wall fell, thousands of Czech students demonstrated in Wenceslas Square in Prague.

Comment: In that context, I would interpret that as: "Just days after..." In other words, it wasn't _weeks_ later, it wasn't _months_ later, it was just _days_ later. It's a vague term, though, it could mean anywhere from 2 to 12 days, roughly, and maybe even longer than that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: Yes, it means "a few days."

It could mean "a few days," but it could also signify a long time if what was expected should have taken hours.

> (For) days after the wall fell, people still were afraid of crossing no-man's land.